# Apache Spark Multi Node Clustering - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark

I am newbie to Apache Spark and Cluster Computing and I implemented Spark in Standalone Mode (Same Machine with Master and Worker), it worked fine for me.

Then, I downloaded pre-built version of spark, and followed these instructions and placed in every nodes of my cluster: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#installing-spark-standalone-to-a-cluster.

My Master node has IP address: 172.17.0.224 and my Slave nodes has IP Address: 172.17.0.221, 172.17.0.222 and 172.17.0.223.

And I edited `slaves` and `spark-env.sh` files to add the IP addresses of my slaves and IP address of my master respectively.

I started the master node `start-master.sh` and started the slave nodes with `start-slaves.sh`, everything worked fine.

I submitted my spark-job using the command `spark-submit --class "Rice" --master spark://172.17.0.224:7077 cs453project/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar cs453project/input.txt cs453project/ouput2 cs453project/ouput3`.

This is the error messages I got:

```
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties 
    15/11/25 11:22:27 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2

    15/11/25 11:22:27 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

15/11/25 11:22:28 WARN Utils: Your hostname, node04 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.17.0.224 instead (on interface eth0)
15/11/25 11:22:28 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ujjwal
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ujjwal
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ujjwal); users with modify permissions: Set(ujjwal)
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@172.17.0.224:58478]
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 58478.
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-bc18e422-d334-4fe5-9663-9439620ec054
15/11/25 11:22:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.3 MB
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-7c6e0ad4-52ae-4f5a-9aaa-6ad9fbf48685/httpd-13d8dd4d-6ff1-450d-baac-f2702c7a4e5b
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 49496.
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.17.0.224:4040
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar at http://172.17.0.224:49496/jars/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar with timestamp 1448479349380
15/11/25 11:22:29 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://172.17.0.224:7077...
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20151125112229-0001
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20151125112229-0001/0 on worker-20151125095922-172.17.0.221-33366 (172.17.0.221:33366) with 2 cores
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20151125112229-0001/0 on hostPort 172.17.0.221:33366 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151125112229-0001/0 is now LOADING
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151125112229-0001/0 is now RUNNING
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 47843.
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 47843
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.17.0.224:47843 with 530.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.17.0.224, 47843)
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/11/25 11:22:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(157248) called with curMem=0, maxMem=556038881
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 153.6 KB, free 530.1 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(14276) called with curMem=157248, maxMem=556038881
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 13.9 KB, free 530.1 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.224:47843 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 530.3 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at build.scala:11
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at build.scala:13
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at build.scala:13) with 108 output partitions
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(count at build.scala:13)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at build.scala:12), which has no missing parents
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3424) called with curMem=171524, maxMem=556038881
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.3 KB, free 530.1 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1934) called with curMem=174948, maxMem=556038881
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1934.0 B, free 530.1 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.224:47843 (size: 1934.0 B, free: 530.3 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 108 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at build.scala:12)
15/11/25 11:22:30 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 108 tasks
15/11/25 11:22:31 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@172.17.0.221:55861/user/Executor#-498212581]) with ID 0
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.17.0.221:49642 with 530.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 172.17.0.221, 49642)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.221:49642 (size: 1934.0 B, free: 530.3 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.221:49642 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 530.3 MB)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 172.17.0.221): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 1]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 2]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 3]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 4]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 5]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 6]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 8) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 7]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 8]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 9]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 12, 172.17.0.221, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2217 bytes)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 10]
15/11/25 11:22:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at build.scala:13) failed in 2.216 s
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 11]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at build.scala:13, took 2.373631 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, 172.17.0.221): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1125)
    at Rice$.main(build.scala:13)
    at Rice.main(build.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 12) on executor 172.17.0.221: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/home/ujjwal/cs453project/input.txt does not exist) [duplicate 12]
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/11/25 11:22:32 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.17.0.224:4040
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
15/11/25 11:22:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7c6e0ad4-52ae-4f5a-9aaa-6ad9fbf48685
```

Could you please help me understand how can I solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The path you used is probably only local to the driver.  You have to use a path that is accessible to all of the workers.  The driver does not send the actual data to the workers - that would be unfortunately slow.  The workers will try to read the data using the path you gave them.  In this case, they will fail because the don't have the files locally.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please suggest me some ideas to work on it?

Comment: Instead of downgrading question people  should  mark question as duplicate or  simply give answer.I know its too late now , but you can use HDFS or s3 bucket  which will act as central data repository accessible to all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

@user3180835, as suggested by @Mike Park, in my case, after I copied the file from local linux file system to hdfs, it started working.

```
hdfs dfs -cp file:///<path_to_local_file> /<hdfs_file_dir>
```